# after postgres import from heroku, rails locally imposes to run database migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to import my database from heroku back to local. Following the commands on [heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export), I can import the entire database locally.

However, Rails is answering I have a pending migration and that I should run `bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`. That fails because the tables already exist.

On heroku:

```
heroku pg:info --app my_app
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.22.7 to 7.24.4.
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           0/20
PG Version:            11.2
```

Localy:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.3
```

`ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version` returns => 20190608070435 
and `db/schema.rb` contains:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_06_10_061746)
```

Replacing that version with the one given by ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version also doesn't help.

Don't know where this problem comes from. After import from Heroku, I have the correct database locally, but rails sees a pending migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses `schema_migrations` table to keep a track of migrations. This issue can happen when a corresponding migration record is missing and rails tries to run the migration. But it fails since you already have the table in your local DB.

If you are sure that you have the latest / up to date database locally, one thing you can do is to run the migration, but commenting out the code (that is in the migration). NOTE: make sure you only comment on the table creation code

E.g

```
class <your migraton name> < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    # commented out code
  end
end
```

That way Rails will update the `schema_migrations` table the correct version and will not nag you again (Rails assumes you've created the table).

Then uncomment the migration file.

Comment: This works. Although it is a bit burdonsome to comment out chunks of code from several files at each import. Isn't there a permanent solution to this?

Comment: Hi @thiebo, this is not at all a permanent solution. This is just to get you running. If you get this error frequently (which ideally you shouldn't), you will have to re visit your deploy workflow and find why this is happening